# How do I parse NSViewTextView RTF to HTML in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have the following code in Swift Coca. I have been through the bowels of the Internet and Stackoverflow with no avail. I was able to find that it might need attributed strings on a data object but I could not understand how that worked.

My code has to do two things:

(a) Convert the variable 'rtf_output' to a regular string value.

(b) Convert the variable 'rtf_output' to an HTML string.

```
@IBAction func BannerButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        let parentTabViewController = self.parent as! TabViewController;       
        
        self.presentAsSheet(sheet);
       
        let dataObj = try! IntroductionTextView.textStorage?.data(from:range);       

        let range = NSMakeRange(0, IntroductionTextView.textStorage?.length ?? 0);

        let rtf_output = IntroductionTextView.rtf(from:range);
     
    }
```

Comment: Why start with the rtf? Why not use `IntroductionTextView.attributedString()`?

Comment: So, I had a windows app that I am converting to Mac. It is a XML document that stored the RTF code from the app. I need to read the file's stored RTF and place it into the TextView control. :-)